# How to add grid-view into tab layout in Android

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-library

I want to have a grid view menu or pop up menu that drop or slid with a button.not a Drawer layout.something like giddylizer app this:
[giddylizer app image](http://lh3.ggpht.com/C9VxpmD-mDr0yuShohELLCWUdSzMkSs_ZcxMIRlRiZzpNNvPHyTX-90_YEo8abeyZl4=h900)
is there any library?any helpful links and suggest...

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion ,  you can achieve that design easily by

1. Add frame layout into your main layout
2. Create two tabs with two fragments
3. Add grid-view into fragments

done.